# Failed rename column while join query

Tags: android, sql, join, android-room

I have a query:

```
@Query("SELECT entries.*, myProfile.myProfileId as my_profile_id FROM Entry as entries LEFT JOIN MyProfile ON entries.user_public_profile_userId = myProfile.myProfileId")
```

I just need to get value from second(right) table and put it into entitys' field - "my_profile_id"  from first table. But nothing works.
this is how field from first table(left) entity look like -

```
 @ColumnInfo(name = "my_profile_id")
val myUserProfileId: Int? = null,
```

and this is how it look like this field from second table (right)

```
 @PrimaryKey
val myProfileId: Int,
```

Result is always null, but condition after ON is working because i tried to change from LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN ad got results, so the only problem here is to map correctly 'myProfileId' into 'my_profile_id'
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full **Entry** and **MyProfile** entities and the POJO you are using for the result of the query (if you don't have one then that could be your issue). Also provide example data that exists in the two tables. Lastly also provide the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the JOIN type using :-

```
SELECT entries.*, myProfile.myProfileId as my_profile_id FROM Entry as entries LEFT JOIN MyProfile ON entries.user_public_profile_userId = myProfile.myProfileId
```

Will result in my_profile_id being the same value that is stored in the user_public_profile_userId column. In that sense the JOIN is a waste  of time.

I suspect that you may want to get another useful value from the MyProfile table.

Assuming that you have an **Entry** entity that is along the lines of :-

```
@Entity
data class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long? = 0,
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "my_profile_id")
    val myUserProfileId: Long? = null,
    val user_public_profile_userId:  Long
)
```

And an **MyProfile** entity that is along the lines of :-

```
@Entity
data class MyProfile(
    @PrimaryKey
    val myProfileId: Long? = null,
    val otherdata: String
)
```

and that you want to get the value from the **otherdata** column then you need an additional POJO to combine the data.

As such consider such a POJO **EntryPlus** :-

```
data class EntryPlus(
    @Embedded
    val entry: Entry,
    val profileIdFromMyProfile: Long,
    val otherdataFromMyProfile: String
)
```

- @Embedded and the following line is saying that you want all the columns/fields from the Entry table
- The other two columns will be from elsewhere (satisfied by the query)

So you could have a Query such as :-

```
 @Query("SELECT entries.*, myProfile.myProfileId AS profileIdFromMyProfile, myProfile.otherdata AS otherdataFromMyProfile  FROM Entry as entries LEFT JOIN MyProfile ON entries.user_public_profile_userId = myProfile.myProfileId")
    fun getMyOtherData(): List<EntryPlus>
```

- i.e. the query is little different BUT importantly uses **`AS`** to name the output columns accordingly to suit the names of the fields in the **EntryPlus** POJO.
- also importantly the result is a list of the POJO (EntryPlus).

**Example**

Consider the following code that:

1. inserts some data (3 MyProfile rows and 2 Entry rows) and then
2. extracts All the Entry rows with no JOIN using `SELECT * FROM entry` and then
3. extracts using your original query and then
4. extracts via the POJO

The code is :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this) // Get database instance
    dao = db.getAllDao() // get the Dao
    dao.deleteAllMyProfile() // Clear the MyProfile table
    dao.deleteAllEntry() // Clear the Entry table
    // Add some profile rows
    dao.insert(MyProfile(1,"myprofile1"))
    dao.insert(MyProfile(2,"myprofile2"))
    dao.insert(MyProfile(3,"myprofile3"))
    // Add some Entry rows (both link to profile1 in this case)
    dao.insert(Entry(100,"Entry1",0,1))
    dao.insert(Entry(200,"Entry2",0,1))

    // Extract 1 All as Entry List (no join)
    for(e: Entry in dao.getAll()) {
        Log.d("ENTRYINFO(1)","Entry Name is ${e.name} EntryID is ${e.id} MapToMyProfile is ${e.user_public_profile_userId} Value is ${e.myUserProfileId}" )
    }
    // Extract 2 All from original query
    for(e: Entry in dao.getMyData()) {
        Log.d("ENTRYINFO(2)","Entry Name is ${e.name} EntryID is ${e.id} MapToMyProfile is ${e.user_public_profile_userId} Value is ${e.myUserProfileId}" )
    }
    // Extract 3 getting useful data from the 2nd (JOINED) table
    for(ep: EntryPlus in dao.getMyOtherData()) {
        Log.d("ENTRYINFO(3)",
            "Entry Name is ${ep.entry.name} EntryID is ${ep.entry.id} MapToMyProfile is ${ep.entry.user_public_profile_userId} Myuserprofile(From Entry) ${ep.entry.myUserProfileId}" +
                    " MyProfileId (From MyProfile) is ${ep.profileIdFromMyProfile} OtherData (From MyProfile) is ${ep.otherdataFromMyProfile}" )
    }
```

The output to the Log is :-

```
2021-07-07 09:44:12.665 D/ENTRYINFO(1): Entry Name is Entry1 EntryID is 100 MapToMyProfile is 1 Value is 0
2021-07-07 09:44:12.665 D/ENTRYINFO(1): Entry Name is Entry2 EntryID is 200 MapToMyProfile is 1 Value is 0

2021-07-07 09:44:12.666 D/ENTRYINFO(2): Entry Name is Entry1 EntryID is 100 MapToMyProfile is 1 Value is 1
2021-07-07 09:44:12.666 D/ENTRYINFO(2): Entry Name is Entry2 EntryID is 200 MapToMyProfile is 1 Value is 1

2021-07-07 09:44:12.667 D/ENTRYINFO(3): Entry Name is Entry1 EntryID is 100 MapToMyProfile is 1 Myuserprofile(From Entry) 0 MyProfileId (From MyProfile) is 1 OtherData (From MyProfile) is myprofile1
2021-07-07 09:44:12.668 D/ENTRYINFO(3): Entry Name is Entry2 EntryID is 200 MapToMyProfile is 1 Myuserprofile(From Entry) 0 MyProfileId (From MyProfile) is 1 OtherData (From MyProfile) is myprofile1
```

**Notes on the Output**

The first two lines note that the MyProfileId value (i.e. Value =) is 0 as was inserted.

The Second two lines, using your original query shows that MyProfileId (Value =) is now the same value as the link/reference/association/relationship (i.e. the `user_public_profile_userId` column) to the MyProfile row.

The Third shows that the values from the MyProfile table (the `otherdata` column) have been extracted.

**However**, you are also appearing to describe the nature of LEFT JOIN in comparison to just JOIN.

If the following line (another Entry row but referencing a non-existent MyProfile row) were added before the extract:-

```
dao.insert(Entry(300,"Entry3",999,10 /* 10 = No such myprofile row */))
```

then the changes in the result will be significant in that the 2nd extract retrieves null for the my_profile_id as per :-

```
D/ENTRYINFO(2): Entry Name is Entry3 EntryID is 300 MapToMyProfile is 10 Value is null
```

changing to just JOIN (not LEFT JOIN) and the row which references the non-existent MyProfile is omitted. This is the documented impact as per :-

> If the join-operator is a "LEFT JOIN" or "LEFT OUTER JOIN", then after the ON or USING filtering clauses have been applied, an extra row is added to the output for each row in the original left-hand input dataset that corresponds to no rows at all in the composite dataset (if any). The added rows contain NULL values in the columns that would normally contain values copied from the right-hand input dataset.

- [SQLite SELECT](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

In the case of null values, if this is your issue, then you need to decide what to do.

- You could for example use the SQLite `COALESCE` function to change the null. e.g. `SELECT entries.*, coalesce(myProfile.myProfileId,9999) as my_profile_id FROM Entry ....`
- Perhaps you need to ensure that the referential integrity is maintained, in which case you can utilise FOREIGN KEYS to enforce referential integrity. Perhaps refer to [Foreign Key](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/ForeignKey)